# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex not matching latin, but only cyrillic characters

Tags: regex, zend-framework

I have defined the following custom routes:

```
; Language
routes.lang.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.lang.route = :lang
routes.lang.defaults.lang = "bg"
routes.lang.defaults.action = "index"
routes.lang.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.lang.defaults.module = "site"
routes.lang.reqs.lang = "[a-z]{2}"

; Article
routes.lang.chains.a.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.lang.chains.a.route = "([^\.html ]+).html$"
routes.lang.chains.a.defaults.action = "index"
routes.lang.chains.a.defaults.controller = "article"
routes.lang.chains.a.defaults.module = "site"
routes.lang.chains.a.map.articleIdent = 1
routes.lang.chains.a.reverse = "%s.html"
```

When I try to access the following url, everything works fine:
http://site.local/en/тест.html -> match

The problem is that when I try to access the url containing only latin characters, the route is being passed:
http://site.local/en/test.html -> not match

I just can't figure it out where is the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the regular expression. In the round brackets I wanted to include everything except ".html", but the syntax is wrong. Well I still don't now that should be the right syntax, but anyway the following change got the job done:

```
routes.lang.chains.a.route = "(.*).html$"
```